# Laravel belongstomany - 3 step relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 interrelated tables

**Companies:** id, name

**CompaniesTags:** id, companies_id, tags_id

**Tags :** id, name

What I want to do is get the name in table tags

Controller

```
$companies = Companies::with("tags")->get();
```

Companies

```
public function tags(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Companies::class, CompaniesTags::class, 'companies_id', 'id');
}
```

Blade

```
@if(isset($company->tags))
    @foreach ($company->tags as $tag)
        {{ $tag->name }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

This is how wrong data is coming help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `tags()` method. The second parameter is the pivot **table**, not the pivot model. If you want to use a specific model for the pivot, you need to specify it after with `using()`

```php
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Companies::class, 'companies_tags', 'companies_id', 'id')
                ->using(CompaniesTag::class);
}
```

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CompaniesTag extends Pivot { ... }
```

```xml
@foreach ($company->tags as $tag)
    {{ $tag->name }}
@endforeach
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\CompaniesTags::fromRawAttributes()

Comment: remove your if (isset(....)) part. Leave only the foreach ... endforeach

Comment: Not working fromRawAttributes

Comment: Oh, right, forgot. You have to make sure CompaniesTags extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot instead of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Comment: not working this way only one data comes
$companies = Companies::with("tags")
return $this->belongsTo(CompaniesTags::class, 'id', 'companies_id');
public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Tags::class, 'tags_id', 'id');
}